# "->>" macro and iterative function application

Tags: clojure

I'm working through a book on clojure and ran into a stumbling block with "->>". The author provides an example of a `comp` that converts `camelCased` keywords into a clojure map with a more idiomatic `camel-cased` approach. Here's the code using comp:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])                               

(def camel->keyword (comp keyword
                          str/join
                          (partial interpose \-)
                          (partial map str/lower-case)
                          #(str/split % #"(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])")))
```

This makes a lot of sense, but I don't really like using `partial` all over the place to handle a variable number of arguments. Instead, an alternative is provided here:

```
(defn camel->keyword
  [s]
  (->> (str/split s #"(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])")
    (map str/lower-case)
    (interpose \-)
    str/join
    keyword))
```

This syntax is much more readable, and mimics the way I would think about solving a problem (front to back, instead of back to front). Extending the `comp` to complete the aforementioned goal...

```
(def camel-pairs->map (comp (partial apply hash-map)
                            (partial map-indexed (fn [i x]
                                                   (if (odd? i)
                                                     x
                                                     (camel->keyword x))))))
```

What would be the equivalent using `->>`? I'm not exactly sure how to thread map-indexed (or any iterative function) using `->>`. This is wrong:

```
(defn camel-pairs->map 
  [s]
  (->> (map-indexed (fn [i x]
         (if (odd? i)
           x
           (camel-keyword x))) 
       (apply hash-map)))
```

Comment: Here's one hint: your `camel-pairs->map` function is not doing anything with the parameter `s` that is passed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three problems: missing a parenthesis, missing the `>` in the name of `camel->keyword`, and not "seeding" your `->>` macro with the initial expression `s`.

```
(defn camel-pairs->map [s]
  (->> s
      (map-indexed 
        (fn [i x] 
          (if (odd? i) 
            x 
            (camel->keyword x)))) 
       (apply hash-map)))
```

Is this really more clear than say?

```
(defn camel-pairs->map [s] 
  (into {} 
    (for [[k v] (partition 2 s)] 
      [(camel->keyword k) v])))
```

Comment: No, that is a much clearer method. I have not yet been exposed to `into` or `partition`. Alas, this is why I'm growing to love clojure: "there's always a better way."

Comment: @Clever 4clojure is your friend! Get at least all the easy and elementary ones done..